# Я скачал Flask в Pycharm через терминал. Хочу вывести код через командную строку но выдает ошибку. Как мне удалить Flask с компьютера?

Tags: python

WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.

Вот это мне пишет командная строка, мне бы удалить flask и снова скачать

Comment: 1 - Warning - не ошибка, а предупреждение, на него можно не обращать внимания. 2 - если просто через терминал пишет, что flask не установлен, а в PyCharm работает, значит PyCharm создал виртуальное окружение, и установил flask туда. Переустанавливать flask не нужно, нужно активировать виртуальное окружение самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение, которое не относится к Flask. Оно лишь говорит, что появилась новая версия pip.

Чтобы убрать "ошибку", введите команду:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

(Если у вас Windows, то вместо python3 запишите python).

Если flask всё-таки нужно переустановить, используйте эти команды:

```
pip uninstall flask
pip install flask
```